# How can I combine two different functions in JavaScript to display the multiples of 2 between zero(0) and n?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to combine two different functions in order to output the multiples of 2 between zero and a parameter n (i.e. 5 in this case). Even though my program is not giving me any bugs, it is not outputting the result either. How can I fix the error?
Thanks

```js
function testFunction(testOk, executethis) {
      if (!testOk) executethis();
    }

    
    function mainFunctin(n) {
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        return i => {
          testFunction(i%2 ==1, ()=>{
            console.log(i, "is even");
          })
        }
      }
    }
    mainFunctin(5);
```

Comment: Unless this is part of an assignment or something which requires being written this way, I would recommend removing the `!` from `testFunction`. It makes reading through `mainFunction` a bit confusing at first glance, since you see, "test if odd" and then "print 'is even'". Just to improve readability at a glance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `return` in the loop.

```js
function testFunction(testOk, executethis) {
  if (!testOk) executethis();
}


function mainFunctin(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    testFunction(i%2 ==1, ()=>{
      console.log(i, "is even");
    })
  }
}

mainFunctin(5);
```